# Change style using children()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to change the "b" color to red with using children. Why doesn't the example above work? How can I make it work?

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="parent1">
        <div class="parent2">
            <b>Text</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(function(){
    $('#wrap').children('parent1').children('parent2').$('b').css('color':'red');
})
```

Here is my jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/L5aSt/

Comment: This whole section is loaded with mistakes: `children('parent1').children('parent2').$('b').css('color':'red')` Try to go one step at a time and you'll be able to see what's going wrong, and really - use a debugger like Firebug...

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of things wrong with your jQuery (at least four different errors).  If you want something as strict as your previous attempt, I would suggest this:

```
$('#wrap > .parent1 > .parent2').css('color', 'red');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hcTkh/

If you just want `.parent2` class items under `#wrap`, then I'd suggest this:

```
$('#wrap .parent2').css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('#wrap')
    .find('b').css('color','red');
})​;​
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L5aSt/1/). All `b`'s inside `#wrap` will be red.

```
$('#wrap .parent2').css('color', 'red'); // Only b's inside parent2 of wrap.
$('#wrap .parent1').css('color', 'red'); // Only b's inside parent1 of wrap (if have any).
```

use following one when you've multiple style rules to apply within one call

```
$('#wrap').find('b').css({'color':'red','font-size':'12px'}); // here an object has been passed as argument.
```

or

```
$('#wrap .parent2').css({'color':'red','font-size':'12px'});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with the other answers. What you're doing isn't probably the "right" way to accomplish your goal :).

That said, to follow the approach you were using the code would look like:

```
$('#wrap').children('.parent1').children('.parent2').children('b').css('color','red');
```

I changed `parent1` to `.parent1` because you are selecting by class.
Same reason on `parent2`.
I replaced `$` with `children` before the `b` and lastly replaced the colon (:) between color and red with a comma.